# Batch inserting multiple mail merge fields

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-word, vba, mail-merge

I have a mail merge document connected to a excel file with around 200 columns and a few hundred rows. I need to setup my mail merge document to look as follows:

```
[code]      [type]     [amount]
[code1]     [type1]    [amount1]
[code2]     [type2]    [amount2]
```

etc, all the way up until the 200th reiteration of the field. Without going into all the details of why I need this, its a super dirty and quick way to get the data we want merged and eventually a more elegant way will be found.

My question is how can I quickly insert the fields without literally selecting insert field several hundred times? Ideally I would just give it a list of the fields and have it insert them all, i.e setup the three columns in excel with the fieldnames, and then copy and paste that into word, except word doesn't then recognize them as actual fields, and will see << text >> as pure text rather than an actual field.

Comment: So you literally are opening a blank document, then inserting those three codes in three columns, and iterating that reference 200 times?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How does this work? It's a macro, so add this to a Module in your document.

```
Sub add_hundreds_of_refs()
Dim myDoc As Document
Set myDoc = ActiveDocument
Dim i As Long

With myDoc
    .MailMerge.Fields.Add Range:=Selection.Range, Name:="Code"
    .MailMerge.Fields.Add Range:=Selection.Range, Name:="Type"
    .MailMerge.Fields.Add Range:=Selection.Range, Name:="Amount"
    Selection.TypeParagraph
    For i = 1 To 200
        .MailMerge.Fields.Add Range:=Selection.Range, Name:="Code" & i
        .MailMerge.Fields.Add Range:=Selection.Range, Name:="Type" & i
        .MailMerge.Fields.Add Range:=Selection.Range, Name:="Amount" & i
        Selection.TypeParagraph
    Next i
End With
End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for, thanks! I'm familiar with VBA in excel, but was having trouble finding much documentation on what the Word commands were in VBA to do this.